# How to use LongPressGesture and Combine with Timer to ‘pump' values to model?

Tags: swiftui, combine

This is for MacOS. I am trying to figure out how I can pump values to my model while the user holds down a custom button. Basically I am trying to recreate a MouseDown/MouseUp combo with a timer firing in between. It doesn’t seem possible with just a LongPressGesture so I have been experimenting with Combine and a Timer but with only partial success. I have the following:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

var cancellable: Cancellable?

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            FastForwardButton().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct FastForwardButton: View {
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .common)
    @GestureState private var isPressed = false
   // @State var cancellable: Cancellable?

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 4)
                    .updating($isPressed, body: { (currentState, state, transaction) in
                        if self.isPressed == false{
                            state = currentState
                            print("Timer Started")
                            cancellable = self.timer.connect()
                        }
                    })
            )

         .onReceive(timer) { time in
            // Do Something here eg myModel.pump()
            print("The time is \(time)")
            if self.isPressed == false{
                print("Timer Cancelled")
                cancellable?.cancel()
              //  cancellable = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above works one time. I get:

"Timer Started"
"The Time is xxx"
.....
"The Time is xxx"
"Timer Cancelled"

But the second press I just get:
"Timer Started"

With no further actions

Note I also had to temporarily move the reference to cancellable outside the View as I got a warning about modifying the View while updating.

Can anyone figure out why the .onReceive closure is only called once? Thanks!

Comment: Timer is not renewable, once invalidated/cancelled it cannot be used again. See [Swiftui timer not firing after navigating back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589527/12299030) topic for possible solution.

Comment: OK thanks that would explain it. I will try recreating the timer each mousedown as per your example

Answer (score 0):

try this (copy - paste - run) macOS

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    var timerPublisher: Timer.TimerPublisher?
    var handle: AnyCancellable?
    var startstop: Cancellable?

    func start() {
        timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default)
        handle = timerPublisher?.sink(receiveValue: {
            print($0)
        })
        startstop = timerPublisher?.connect()
        print("start")
    }
    func stop() {
        startstop?.cancel()
        print("stop")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.model.start()
            }) {
                Text("Start")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.model.stop()
            }) {
                Text("Stop")
            }
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

it shows two buttons and you can start stop publishing ... (Apsperi is right that once publisher is canceled, it is not usable again. It is true for any publisher, not specific for Timer.Publisher.

[image]

if you like to "publish" some changes in your model you can do it some standard way

```
func start() {
    timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default)
    handle = timerPublisher?.sink(receiveValue: {
        print($0)
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    })
    startstop = timerPublisher?.connect()
    print("start")
}
```

The question is why not simply use .autoconnect() ?? The answer is flexibility, think about this model

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    var timerPublisher: Timer.TimerPublisher?
    var handle: AnyCancellable?
    var startstop: Cancellable?
    func createTimerPublisher() {
        timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default)
        handle = timerPublisher?.sink(receiveValue: {
            print($0)
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
    init() {
        createTimerPublisher()
    }
    func start() {
        startstop = timerPublisher?.connect()
        print("start")
    }
    func stop() {
        startstop?.cancel()
        print("stop")
        // or create it conditionaly for later use
        createTimerPublisher()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE where mouse-up and mouse-down on some View starts / stops the timer**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    var timerPublisher: Timer.TimerPublisher?
    var handle: AnyCancellable?
    var startstop: Cancellable?
    func createTimerPublisher() {
        timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default)
        handle = timerPublisher?.sink(receiveValue: {
            print($0)
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
    init() {
        createTimerPublisher()
    }
    func start() {
        // if
        startstop = timerPublisher?.connect()
        print("start")
    }
    func stop() {
        startstop?.cancel()
        startstop = nil
        print("stop")
        // or create it conditionaly for later use
        createTimerPublisher()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.model.start()
            }) {
                Text("Start")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.model.stop()
            }) {
                Text("Stop")
            }
            MouseUpDownRepresentable(content: Rectangle()).environmentObject(model)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

class MouseUpDownViewClass<Content>: NSHostingView<Content> where Content : View {
    let model: Model
    required init(model: Model, rootView: Content) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required init(rootView: Content) {
        fatalError("init(rootView:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("mouse up")
        model.stop()
    }
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("mouse down")
        model.start()
    }
}

struct MouseUpDownRepresentable<Content>: NSViewRepresentable where Content: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    let content: Content

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSHostingView<Content> {
        return MouseUpDownViewClass(model: model, rootView: self.content)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSHostingView<Content>, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

If it looks too complex, you can **create it solely with SwiftUI gesture**. The trick uses different gesture recognition

```
struct TouchView: View {
    @State var pressed = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle().fill(pressed ? Color.yellow : Color.orange)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ (touch) in
                        if self.pressed == false {
                            self.pressed = true
                            print("start")
                        }
                    })
                    .onEnded({ (touch) in
                        print("stop")
                        self.pressed = false
                    })
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't what I am after. I basically want to start a timer on the SwiftUI equivalent of mouse down and stop it again on mouse up.

Comment: and what is the trouble? mouse down -> start, mouse up -> stop ...

Comment: @Peter do you have trouble with mouseUp, mouseDown events? This is totally different question and it could be solved with similar approach as is described in https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/ or simply check NSHostingView (where you can track your mouse events)

Comment: @Peter updated with mouse up/down to start/stop the timer publisher

Comment: Thank you user3441734. My original comment was because you used different buttons to start and stop the timer, but your updated answers, particularly the last one, work great for my situation. I actually tried a DragGesture before but never quite got it to work. Thanks again!